# Extracting a number from a string

Tags: c, string

I am trying to write a function in C that takes a string, for example: `"abc123def"` and returns a number in string form: `"123"`.

I have little experience with C so I was wondering if I am using the `isDigit()` function correctly. My code is below, if there is a better way to solve the problem I would appreciate help. Thanks!

```
char findNumber(char *str1)
{
    char num1[] = "";
    int i = 0;
    int j = 0;
    while(str1[i] != '\0') {
            if(isDigit(str1[i])) {
                    num1[j] = str1[i];
                    j++;
            }
            i++;
    }
    num1[j] = '\0';
    return num1;
}

int main(int argc, const char* argv[])
{
    char str2[] = "!3254";
    printf(findNumber(str2));
    return 0;
}
```

I'm getting errors such as:

```
undefined reference to `isDigit'
```

and

```
return makes integer from pointer without a cast
```

What could be causing these?

Comment: That's a poorly worded question. What if the string is something like `"abc123def456ghi"`?

Comment: Seems fine to me, but you didn't allocate space for `num1` in your method. You might want to read up on C memory allocation (try searching for the difference between static and dynamic memory allocation). *edit* Also looks like Kerrek SB is right... the requirements are a bit poorly defined. If we can assume that the input string will only ever contain one number then you should be okay

Comment: Yea sorry, the original string only has one number. I am getting errors such as "undefined reference to `isDigit'"  and "return makes integer from pointer without a cast"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your function needs to return `char *` since you're not just returning a single character, but a bunch of characters.

After a quick Google search I found that `isdigit` is defined in `ctype.h`, so lower-case `D` and include `ctype.h`.

Also, you've got yourself some [undefined behaviour](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) there, since you only allocate memory to `num1` for a length 0 string. `char *num1 = malloc(someSize)` is one option, which should have a corresponding `free` somewhere if the program were to execute for anything more than a few seconds / minutes.

Code after fixes:

```
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define MAX_SIZE 100

char *findNumber(char *str1)
{
    char *num1 = malloc(MAX_SIZE);
    // using "strlen(str1)+1" instead of MAX_SIZE might be preferred
    int i = 0, j = 0;
    while(str1[i] != '\0') {
            if(isdigit(str1[i])) {
                    num1[j] = str1[i];
                    j++;
            }
            i++;
    }
    num1[j] = '\0';
    return num1;
}

int main(int argc, const char* argv[])
{
    char str2[] = "!3254";
    printf(findNumber(str2));
    return 0;
}
```

[Test](http://ideone.com/q32msD).

Comment: Thanks a lot the d in isdigit() was the cause of a lot of errors. Your solutions work but I am getting a warning: warning: incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function ‘malloc’
Is that something to worry about?

Comment: Given a string `"abc123def456"`, this code will return `"123456"`.  If that's the intention, great; if not, then the algorithm probably needs to use `strpbrk()` or `strcspn()` (from `<string.h>` to find the first digit, and then copy it and subsequent digits up to the first non-digit.

Comment: Perfect, thanks Dukeling and Jonathan Leffler. @JonathanLeffler The string will have at most 1 number so the example input above is never going to be the case.

Answer (score 2):

This should work:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

char* findNumber(char *str1)
{
    char* num1=malloc(strlen(str1)+1);//allocate memory for the number
    int i = 0;
    int j = 0;
    while(str1[i] != '\0') {
            if(isdigit(str1[i])) {//isdigit() is in ctype.h
                    num1[j] = str1[i];
                    j++;
            }
            i++;
    }
    num1[j] = '\0';
    return num1;
}

int main(int argc, const char* argv[])
{
    char str2[] = "!3254";
    char* number=findNumber(str2);
    printf("%s\n",number);
    free(number);//free the allocated memory
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Given a string `"abc123def456"`, this code will return `"123456"`.  If that's the intention, great; if not, then the algorithm probably needs to use `strpbrk()` or `strcspn()` (from `<string.h>` to find the first digit, and then copy it and subsequent digits up to the first non-digit.